# Magento promotions shopping cart price rule - combined simple and downloadable products

Tags: magento

Hope someone can help here...
Magento 1.7.0.2
I have created a very simple shopping cart price rule.
If total quantity in cart is greater than 1 > apply 10% discount.

This works fine, if i have 2 simple products in my cart or if i have 2 downloadable products in cart.
But if i have 1 simple and 1 downloadable, no discount is added.

This worked fine on an older version of magento.

I have tried to change to rule, to look at the subtotal of the cart, but it is stille the same.

Hope someone, can give me an idear of why this is happening.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just for confirmation as it is working for me

you got to `Promotions > Shopping Basket Rules > Then create new rule`.

under conditions set the following:

If ALL  of these conditions are `TRUE : Total Items Quantity`  equals or greater than  3

Then under actions:

for the Apply dropdown: choose `Fixed amount discount for the whole basket` then below this add your percentage.

This is the basic requirement. There are more settings you can / tweak apply here.

Hope that helps?

Comment: same conditions, ecxept i have eauals or creater than 1
actions: i have tried: fixed amount for the whole cart and percent of product price discount..

As mentioned, if i have 2 or more simple products in cart, the rule is applied.
if i have 2 or more downloadable products in cart, the rule is applied..
if i have 1 or more simple products + 1 or more downloadable products in cart, the rule will not be applied